# Raspberry Pi auto login without etc/inittab

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I would like to settup my Raspberry Pi to auto login in a specific user.
I googled this and the solutions that i found were about editing the /etc/inittab file. My problem is now i dont have that file, it appears to be missing in my version of Raspbian. 
Is there another way to do this?

Comment: what version of raspian do you have installed? what is the sessionmanager?

Comment: Raspbian GNU/LINUX 8

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/48241/auto-login-in-jessie-how

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're using the latest Raspian-Image (jessie). This one is based on Debian 8 (jessie) where the init-system changed from sysvinit to systemd. I think that it could have something to do with your problem. If you google: `raspbian jessie auto login` you should find a solution for your problem.

p.e. 
[this link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/how-to-enable-automatic-login-on-debian-8-jessie-for-console-4175550342/) provides a possible solution:

```
$ sudo -i
# mkdir -pv /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d
# nano /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf
```

insert the following text:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin $username --noclear I 38400 linux
```

make sure that `$username` is your username

Then reboot.

**optional:**

If you want to start the X-Server automatically, just add the following line at the end of your ~/.profile

```
[[ -z $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]] && exec startx
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work, it interrupts raspberry boot.

Comment: Raspbian works a little differently, please see my answer and its link to the Raspberry Pi SE

Answer (score 6):

My autologin.conf file appears as below. Note the `%I`, my pi hangs otherwise:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin pi --noclear %I 38400 linux
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  The solution @TomMekken 's solution didn't work for me, but @Steve 's did.  For me the "extra" `ExecStart=` was critical.

Comment: this definitely works for the newest Raspberry 9 Stretch

Answer (score 2):

I found this, which is the only thing that worked for me.

#### Automatic Login for LightDM

Open the terminal and make first a backup of the file we are going to edit:

```
su - 
gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.back
```

Edit now this file:

```
gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

or

```
nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Uncomment these two lines:

```
autologin-user=USERNAME
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

Replace USERNAME with your own username. Save the file and exit. Run now this command so that changes are taken into effect:

```
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Answer (score 2):

I use `raspi-config`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo raspi-config
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/default.target → /lib/systemd/system/graphical.target.
```

There's a **menu** that comes up wherein you select **`Boot Options`** then something along the lines of `B1 Boot Desktop Options` and finally you select among several auto login options.

See: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/48241/auto-login-in-jessie-how

Comment: This is by far the easiest option. Boot Options > Desktop / CLI > Console Autologin. The symlink wasn't necessary -- just launch raspi-config and select the option.