# How to let linux(raspberry) run python script when plugin power?

Tags: python, linux, bash, raspberry-pi2

I have a python script(`namely /home/pi/x.py`). And I have tried a lot of ways to let the program, some thing such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
# /etc/init.d/mystart  
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: Python
```

> **(I am thinking am I right here(Provides: Python)?)**

```
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: my python initscript
# Description: no description
### END INIT INFO   case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting x.py "
        /home/pi/x.py &
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping x.py"
        #killall x.py
        kill $(ps aux | grep -m 1 'python /home/pi/x.py' | awk '{ print $2 }')
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: service x.py start|stop"
        exit 1
        ;; esac exit 0
```

I have modified this bash from its original form, and put it in

```
/etc/inti.d/mystart
```

`sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/mystart`

`sudo update-rc.d mystart defaults`

However, when I try to:`sudo service mystart start`

Some error comes out!
*`[Unit mystart.service failed to load: No such file or directory.]`*

> So I'm blocked here, I dont know how to let x.py run while it the
>   power is on

Comment: not every script can run as a service: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603109/how-to-make-a-python-script-run-like-a-service-or-daemon-in-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `crontab` and it works well

**Step 1:**

```
sudo crontab -e
```

**Step 2:** fill in it

```
@reboot python /home/pi/x.py &
```

**Step 3:** Save it and reboot

Answer (score 2):

Open /etc/profile

```
sudo nano /etc/profile
```

Scroll to the bottom and add the following line :

```
sudo python /home/pi/x.py
```

where “/home/pi/x.py” is the absolute path to your script.
Type “Ctrl+X” to exit, then “Y” to save followed by “Enter” twice. Now reboot and test. python script should now run on startup

**Auto Login Setup(to execute script without any intervention from user)**

- Open /etc/inittab

  sudo nano /etc/inittab
- Find this line

  1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 115200 tty1
- Add a # character to the beginning of the line to disable it so it looks like

  #1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 115200 tty1
- Under that line, add the following:

  1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f pi tty1 /dev/tty1 2>&1

where “pi” is the username. Type “Ctrl+X” to exit, then “Y” to save followed by “Enter” twice. Now on startup, raspberrypi will autologin with `pi` user and execute your script

**What if you don't have /etc/inittab?**

I assume you're using the latest Raspian-Image (jessie). This one is based on Debian 8 (jessie) where the init-system changed. Autologin solution is already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33757767/2073920)

**Source:**
http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/02/how-to-autorun-a-python-script-on-raspberry-pi-boot/

Comment: Hey @Abdul Rauf Mujahid ! Your answer makes me go closer to my goal! thank you!  However, I have to log in my account to let x.py do the job! How can I let it run the script when I plug in the power?

Comment: I have tried this, but I have no file `/etc/inittab`

Comment: @Microos  check "What if you don't have /etc/inittab?" portion of my answer