# LockScreen doesnt ask for password on parrotSec OS

Tags: passwords, lockscreen, debian-based, parrot-os

I downloaded [my parrot-OS OVA from the official site](https://download.parrot.sh/parrot/iso/4.9.1/Parrot-security-4.9.1_virtual.ova) and now when I start the VM on virtual box, it directly logs me in and doesn´t ask for a password.
I changed the passwords from the terminal, yet the lock screen just logs me in as soon as I click anything on the UI.

I checked settings and couldn't find anything via the UI.

---

Parrot 4.9.1

Answer (score 0):

Do you know, if you run LightDM, the defailt DisplayManager from Pirrot?

If so, you can change the config `suod nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and comment the lines that start with `autologin-user...` by insert a `#`infront.

Then you can logout and restart lightdm - or just reboot to see if it worked.

Source: Doing the inverse of [Automatic Login for LightDM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33753985/raspberry-pi-auto-login-without-etc-inittab/40323702#40323702)